# How are grids made?

Tags: c#, unity, grid

I've been looking at tutorials and researching forums and such but I still can't understand how the grids are made. I get confused at parts like this.

```
for (int x = 0; x < Size.x; x++) {
   for (int z = 0; z< Size.z; z++) {
        Instantiate(PlatPrefab, new Vector3(x+platX,platY,z+playZ), Quaternion.identity);
    }
 }
```

i get confused at the `for` stuff that I see in a lot of grid code. Basically I just want to know how grids are made in a proper code example in c# and how the code itself works not just how to write it. The type of grid would be in 3d.

Comment: If you know where you are confused, then it seems you know how to solve your problem. Blocks of looping code is a fundamental concept in imperative programming languages. Lists and arrays are simple data structures, that are critical to doing even simple things.

Comment: the only thing im still slightly unsure about is whats happening here int x = 0; x < 8; x++) i know its add 1 more ..******* but what is the x<8 part doing is that pretty much just assigning the amount of rows there are in this grid.... and why does x have to be less then 8 and is x=0 like when the grid is suppose to start counting *******that part still confuses me Little but aside from that your answer plus the visual refrence made the code so much easier to read .. thank you my good sir @Byte56

Comment: @johnsmith - the `x < 8` portion is the anchor statement. Or, [For Loop on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop)

Answer (score 4):

You likely want to start with something simpler than creating a game if you get stuck at `for` loops. Here's the basic idea for creating a grid, you pretty much have everything you need.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
   for (int z = 0; z < 8; z++) {
        Instantiate(SquareObject, new Vector3(x,0,z), Quaternion.identity);
    }
 }
```

This is a nested loop example. When looking at a grid, imagine you want to place something inside each square. An algorithm for making sure you touch each square would be similar to the above. You can think of `x` as a column position and think of `y` as a row position. That means for any `x`, `y` pair, you have the coordinates of a grid location. For example, the very bottom left square in a grid would be x:0, y:0. The one to the right of that would be x:1, y:0. Like so:

[image]

The nested `for` loops are going to iterate through and give you each pair of `x` and `y` coordinates possible. This gives you the position of every square inside the grid.

Now that we're getting every position, we can do something with it. That's what the `Instantiate` call is doing. It's creating an object at each grid position. In this case, it's placing a prefab called `SquareObject`. It's setting the position of the object with: `new Vector3(x,0,z)`. As the image shows above, those position spaced in a grid fashion.